# Angular Bootstrap Install error

Tags: angular, installation, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to install ng bootstrap but am getting an error which seems itself to be an error. The following is the message I get when I run the install, below is my package.json file.

```
Dan:solomon-2 dp$ npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
solomon-2@0.0.0 /Users/dp/solomon-2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.2.1 invalid
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/core@~2.4.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.2.1 invalid
└── @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.19 

npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.19 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.19 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.19 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/tsc-wrapped@^0.5.0 but none was installed.
```

---

```
{
  "name": "solomon-2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.19",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use latest version of angular2 (@angular) libraries. Error messages shows ng2-bootatrap required @angular/core@~2.4.0 ,@angular/common@2.2.1 etc...

Answer (score 1):

There's no error, just a few warnings about unmet peer dependencies due to ng-bootstrap listed `@angular/core@^2.3.1, @angular/common@^2.3.1 and @angular/forms@^2.3.1` as a dependency and you have version 2.4.0 installed. Npm uses semver for versioning therefore `^2.3.1 !== 2.4.0`.